# Add temporary property to node in Neo4j Cypher for return

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I am using the Neo4j .Net client to interface with a Neo4j database.

I often come by this issue when trying to map related nodes to nested classes :

For example mapping

```
(:Foo)-[:FOOBAR]->(:Bar)
```

to the form

```
public class Foo {
    public string FooPropOne { get; set; }
    public string FooPropTwo { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }  
}

public class Bar {
    public string BarPropOne { get; set; }
    public string BarPropTwo { get; set; }
}
```

To get the correct output for deserialzation I have to write the query like so:

```
Foo foo = WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(f:Foo)-[:FOOBAR]->(b:Bar)")
    .With("@{
                FooPropOne: f.FooPropOne,
                FooPropTwo: f.FooPropTwo,
                Bars: collect(b)
             } AS Result")
    .Return<Foo>("Result")
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

To a certain extent this is fine, and works perfectly, but becomes quite unwieldy the more properties the Foo class has.

I was wondering if there was something I can do in the "With" statement to add a temporary property (in the above case "Bars") when returning the nodes, that does not require me to write every single property on the parent node?

Something like

```
.With("f.Bars = collect(b)")
.Return<Foo>("f")
```

that wont actually affect the data stored in the DB?

Thanks in advance for any relpies!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to add a temporary property like you want, personally - I would take one of two approaches, and the decision really comes down to what you like to do.

### Option 1

*The choosing properties version*

```
var foo = client.Cypher
    .Match("(f:Foo)-[:FOOBAR]->(b:Bar)")
    .With("f, collect(b) as bars")
    .Return((f, bars) => new Foo
    {
        FooPropOne = f.As<Foo>().FooPropOne,
        FooPropTwo = f.As<Foo>().FooPropTwo,
        Bars = Return.As<List<Bar>>("bars")
    }).Results.SingleOrDefault();
```

This version allows you to be Type Safe with your objects you're bringing out, which on a class with lots of properties does limit the chance of a typo creeping in. This will give you back a `Foo` instance, so no need to do any other processing.

### Option 2

*The little bit of post-processing required version*

```
var notQuiteFoo = client.Cypher
    .Match("(f:Foo)-[:FOOBAR]->(b:Bar)")
    .With("f, collect(b) as bars")
    .Return((f, bars) => new
    {
        Foo = f.As<Foo>(),
        Bars = bars.As<List<Bar>>()
    }).Results;
```

This saves on the typing out of the properties, so in a big class, a time saver, and also means if you add extra properties you don't need to remember to update the query. *However* you do need to do some post-query processing, something like:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = notQuiteFoo.Results.Select(r => {r.Foo.Bars = r.Bars; return r.Foo;});
```

Personally - I like **Option 2** as it has less potential for Typos, though I appreciate neither is exactly what you're after.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your response. So basically, no, I am going to have to write out the properties each time. While I like your solutions I often have classes nested two or three levels deep (I.E.: the last question of mine you answered), and I prefer creating the correct data structure in Cypher (as I assume its more efficient), rather then doing a lot of post processing to build up my class hierarchies. Thanks again for both your answers though, they've been very helpfull...

Comment: In terms of CPU, I'd have thought between 1/2 there's not much in it, both will bring back the same amount of data. The 2nd option sends a smaller packet across the wire as it doesn't need to ask for each property by name, so it depends on whether you want to be more efficient CPU locally or HTTP call, the HTTP call would I imagine be more noticeable.. :/

Comment: Can someone please translate the solution to a Cypher Query